# Monitor RESTful API Web Service with Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

We have a RESTful API web service that we would like to monitor with Zabbix. We have sample JSON scripts that check the functionality of the API service.

I understand that Zabbix can do simple web monitoring by logging into pages and looking for specific keywords and what not. Can it also be configured to perform JSON API calls such as GET and POST?

Please help can't find anything in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get the web service checks to work properly, what you need to setup is an external check as described at http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/external

Then you make a shell/perl/php/whatever script that does the checks you want, and prints something like FAILED when the service is down.

Your script goes in the directory specified in your zabbix configuration for ExternalScripts - likely something like /etc/zabbix/externalscripts. Make sure it has appropriate permissions for the zabbix user to be able to execute it.

In the template or host, create a new item, and set the type to external check, and set the key to the name of your script.

Then create a trigger that looks for the "FAILED" line and alerts you.